# Intermediate bash output in Jupyter notebook

Tags: bash, output, jupyter-notebook

When I run this in terminal:

```
cd 1st_flask_app_1/
python3 app.py
```

I get the output:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

When I try to run the same command in a Jupyter notebook with the cell magic `%%bash`, I get no printed output, but the web app still starts up and I can visit it. If I then stop the cell I get the output:

```
Process is interrupted.
```

So it looks like the Jupyter notebook with `%%bash` cell magic is printing final command outputs, but not intermediate outputs. Is there any way to also print the intermediate outputs?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason it looks like your `stdout`/`stderr` are not properly attached to your bash...

Could you try to redirect your command `stdout` and `stderr` to a log file in append mode?

```
python3 app.py >> application.log 2>&1
```

or you could also pipe it with `tee`

```
python3 app.py 2>&1 | tee -a application.log
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks, but I think I tried this a couple months ago and it didn't end up solving my problem. I don't have it in front of me to double check at the moment.